# Decode Java Base64 string in C?

Tags: java, c

How to decode string in C, which was encoded to Base64 in Java ?
I have string, which was encoded to Base64 in Java.
Now I need decode this string in C. How can I do that ?

I used some Base64 library in C, but result was the same.
Decoded data are not the same as their original from Java.
When I use readable ASCII chars as input data, it will work, but I need all data in range -127 +128.

**Short sample of my encoded data:** *"flBJQ1RVUkV8AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAAA/wAAAP8AAAD/AAA"*

**This is part of code which I used for decoding of Base64:**

```
// Make sure we have enough space to add '\0' character at end.
      dec = (unsigned char *) b64_realloc(dec, size + 1);
      if (dec != NULL){
        dec[size] = '\0';
      } else {
        return NULL;
      }

      // Return back the size of decoded string if demanded.
      if (decsize != NULL) {
        *decsize = size;
      }

      return dec;
    }

    unsigned char *b64_decode_ex3 (const char *src, size_t len, size_t *decsize) {
      int i = 0;
      int j = 0;
      int l = 0;
      size_t size = 0;
      unsigned char *dec = NULL;
      unsigned char buf[3];
      unsigned char tmp[4];

      // alloc
      dec = (unsigned char *) b64_malloc(1);
      if (NULL == dec) { return NULL; }

      // parse until end of source
      while (len--) {
        // break if char is `=' or not base64 char
        if ('=' == src[j]) { break; }
        //if (!(isalnum(src[j]) || '+' == src[j] || '/' == src[j])) { break; }

        // read up to 4 bytes at a time into `tmp'
        tmp[i++] = src[j++];

        // if 4 bytes read then decode into `buf'
        if (4 == i) {
          // translate values in `tmp' from table
          for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
            // find translation char in `b64_table'
            for (l = 0; l < 64; ++l) {
              if (tmp[i] == b64_table[l]) {
                tmp[i] = l;
                break;
              }
            }
          }

          // decode
          buf[0] = (tmp[0] << 2) + ((tmp[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
          buf[1] = ((tmp[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((tmp[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
          buf[2] = ((tmp[2] & 0x3) << 6) + tmp[3];

          // write decoded buffer to `dec'
          dec = (unsigned char *) b64_realloc(dec, size + 3);
          if (dec != NULL){
            for (i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
              dec[size++] = buf[i];
            }
          } else {
            return NULL;
          }

          // reset
          i = 0;
        }
      }

      // remainder
      if (i > 0) {
        // fill `tmp' with `\0' at most 4 times
        for (j = i; j < 4; ++j) {
          tmp[j] = '\0';
        }

        // translate remainder
        for (j = 0; j < 4; ++j) {
            // find translation char in `b64_table'
            for (l = 0; l < 64; ++l) {
              if (tmp[j] == b64_table[l]) {
                tmp[j] = l;
                break;
              }
            }
        }

        // decode remainder
        buf[0] = (tmp[0] << 2) + ((tmp[1] & 0x30) >> 4);
        buf[1] = ((tmp[1] & 0xf) << 4) + ((tmp[2] & 0x3c) >> 2);
        buf[2] = ((tmp[2] & 0x3) << 6) + tmp[3];

        // write remainer decoded buffer to `dec'
        dec = (unsigned char *) b64_realloc(dec, size + (i - 1));
        if (dec != NULL){
          for (j = 0; (j < i - 1); ++j) {
            dec[size++] = buf[j];
          }
        } else {
          return NULL;
        }
      }

      // Make sure we have enough space to add '\0' character at end.
      dec = (unsigned char *) b64_realloc(dec, size + 1);
      if (dec != NULL){
        dec[size] = '\0';
      } else {
        return NULL;
      }

      // Return back the size of decoded string if demanded.
      if (decsize != NULL) {
        *decsize = size;
      }

      return dec;
    }
```

Comment: *I need all data in range -127 +128.*  But you seem to be using `unsigned char`?  That will be in the range of 0 to 255.

Comment: It is possible to convert it to range 0..255, but without lost any data. No data are same as original now (except readable). I didn't analyze this code from library, but I did my own base64 decoder and result was the same.

Comment: Note that Java's `char`s, from which its `String`s are built, are *16-bit*, *unsigned* integers, whereas C `char`s are typically 8 bits wide and may be either signed or unsigned.  The corresponding data type in C would be `uint16_t`, which for many implementations is the same thing as `unsigned short`.

Comment: For the record, Base64 is an encoding scheme that doesn't depend on any programming language.  Java is not relevant, unless you used some Java-specific binary format that you then encoded using Base64.  (And if you did that, then you will need to take the binary format into account as well.)

Comment: Additionally, "encoded to Base64 in Java" is hardly a complete specification for how your data were encoded.  There are more than a dozen reasonably well-known variations of Base64, with at least 8 of those defined in various Internet RFCs.  Smart decoders can adapt to multiple variations, but some variations have features that you need to know about and account for explicitly.

Comment: Furthermore, inasmuch as Java Strings are composed of 16-bit units, but Base-64 encodes sequences of 8-bit units, you have a character encoding issue lurking under the surface, too.  Your encoder must first convert `char`s to bytes -- this is the character encoding, and there are multiple ways to do it -- and a corresponding decoder must decode those bytes correctly to recover the original sequence of 16-bit units.

Comment: "Your encoder must first convert chars to bytes" - I used this `String encmess = Base64.encodeToString(str, Base64.DEFAULT); ` in Java where str is byte array.